# High Voltage applied to TVS diode

Tags: voltage, tvs

I am using the below input circuit which has this [SM6T36CAY](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/sm6ty.pdf) 36V TVS diode.

The input voltage range is 12-36V and the output is the same only dropping the diode forward voltage.

Typical load current is around 80mA.

[image]

My case :

I applied around 130V at the input side by mistake which resulted in the magic smoke. 
After turning off the power supply and adjusting it to the nominal voltage range, the typical current draw increased from the usual 80mA to 500mA.

Upon debugging, I checked the individual power rails. This 12-36V is converted to 5V by the LDO which is fed to the microcontroller. I found that the 5V rail was showing short (continuity) and therefore, I replaced the microcontroller thinking that it might be damaged. But After replacing the microcontroller also, same result of 500mA current draw.

Later, I checked the resistance across the TVS diode. It was showing some 10-50Ohms only.

After changing the TVS Diode, the current draw reduced to 80mA nominal.

I thought TVS was to handle transient voltages. And I applied that 130V for some 30seconds.

My questions :

1. TVS diodes are not capable of handling some hundreds of volts for 30-45seconds but they can handle kV range for few micro or milliseconds. Why is that?
2. And why did the current draw was high till I replaced the TVS? The TVS was a short circuit impedance path for the current?
3. If the TVS diode was the only problem, why did my LDO output (5V) also show a short circuit?

Comment: Transient and time is relative. 30 seconds is an eternity in electronic timescales

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *TVS diodes are not capable of handling some hundreds of volts for
>   30-45seconds but they can handle kV range for few micro or
>   milliseconds. Why is that?*

As with all use examples of TVS diodes, they are trying to fight-off a surge of current. They cannot fight against a solid voltage source because if you applied one there would be theoretically tens of thousands of amps. So, the voltage source they "fight-against" is not a true voltage source because it has series impedance. It doesn't matter whether the surge is indirect lightning or ESD - there is a series impedance that limits the current and the TVS takes this current and clamps the voltage to a peak or limiting value.

However, it will only do this for a certain length of time before the internal temperature of the junction gets too hot and it melts.

Surges are limited in time to a few hundred micro seconds so why should a TVS diode be designed to fight-off a surge that lasted several seconds?

> *And why did the current draw was high till I replaced the TVS? The TVS
>   was a short circuit impedance path for the current?*

Because the internals of the TVS melted and it turned into a good conductive blob of semiconductor material.

> *If the TVS diode was the only problem, why did my LDO output (5V) also
>   show a short circuit?*

Look at the data sheet: -

[image]

The TVS might have allowed a voltage as high as 49.9 volts or maybe 64.3 volts when you applied the 130 volt supply. It might even of allowed a higher voltage - it all depends on how much current the 130 volt supply can muster.

Is your LDO capable of withstanding 50 volts?

---

### How hot will it get

The device weighs 0.11 grams and lets say it is subjected to a terminal voltage of 50 volts at 12 amps for 10 seconds. The power is 600 watts and the energy is 6,000 joules. Now consider a material that has a really good specific heat. I'm thinking water and water has a specific heat of 4.186 joules per gram per degC. In other words, if you apply a heat of 4.186 joules to 1 gram of water it will warm 1 degC.

So, with 600 joules applied, 1 gram of water will warm 143.3 degC and 0.11 gram of water would warm by 1303 degC.

Do you see why a small 0.11 gram TVS diode will turn to a molten blob in a few seconds. Once it's got past 600 degC it's done for. The specific heat of silicon os only 0.7 joules per gram per degree Celsius so it would likely melt in less than a second.

Comment: Thank you. My absolute maximum ratings of the LDO is 40V. And 2 questions for your answer. 1. I can understand that voltage and current are inter-related. So, when you say "They fight a surge of current" - Shouldn't the ratings of the TVS diodes focus on providing "what's the maximum current it can handle, rather than providing the maximum voltage that it will clamp"? And 2. When you say, "So, the voltage source they "fight-against" is not a true voltage source because it has series impedance" - Who is "they" and "it" in the above line? I thought all voltage sources have series impedance?

Comment: And if you would like me to move the 1st question of my previous comment into a new question, I will do. But please provide some help with the second question and the voltage sources which won't/will have series impedance

Comment: (1) The rating table in my answer show both voltage and current limits. Batteries (for example) are specified in volts and secondarily in mAh then, if you are lucky in mA or amps. (2) "they" is it, the TVS diode. All voltage supplies have series impedance, yes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer